# Как применить шаблон ко всем подкатегориям?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Как применить шаблон ко всем подкатегориям родительской категории? Пока шаблон применяется только к самой родительской категории и к первой подкатегории, нужно чтобы применялось ко всем подкатегориям  и подпод...

```
<?php

  $termID = 113;
  $taxonomyName = "product_cat";
  $childrens = get_term_children( $termID, $taxonomyName );
  
  if ( (has_term( 'zakaznaya-produktsiya', 'product_cat')) || (has_term($childrens, 'product_cat')) ) {
    wc_get_template( 'archive-product-custom.php' );
  }
  else { wc_get_template( 'archive-product.php' );
  }


 ?>
```

Comment: Убрать это и учить https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2#.D0.9E.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.B1.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B6.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D1.80.D1.83.D0.B1.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BA.D0.B8

Comment: @SeVlad Если Вы имеете ввиду назвать файл taxonomy-product_cat-zakaznaya-produktsiya.php , то он тоже распространяется только на род.категорию